# Access macOS reminders from Python

Tags: python, objective-c, macos

How do I access the reminders database (a.k.a EventKit) from Python on macOS? Everything I've found online uses pythonista, but that only runs on iOS. I was able to port `objc_util.py` to macOS, such that this works:

`NSObject = ObjCClass('NSObject')`

but this doesn't:

`EKEventStore = ObjCClass('EKEventStore')`

Annoyingly, even this doesn't work:

`NSDate = ObjCClass('NSDate')`

It says that NSDate isn't found. So I think that the code is missing something serious.